# Ubuntu 16.04 USB 3.0 UAS support

Tags: usb

I am receiving the following failure message from an [ICY DOCK HDD disk enclosure](http://www.icydock.com/goods.php?id=189):

```
USB controller 0000:04:00.0 does not support streams, which are required by the UAS driver.
```

Supposedly the 4.4 kernel supports UAS & UASP so what's happening?

Output of `dmesg |grep usb`

```
[ 3554.004547] usb 7-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3554.020553] usb 7-2: device firmware changed
[ 3554.020754] usb 7-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 3554.700361] usb 7-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 3554.716781] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0562
[ 3554.716793] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 3554.716803] usb 7-2: Product: JMS56x Series
[ 3554.716812] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[ 3554.716820] usb 7-2: SerialNumber: RANDOM__E3F4917AD758
[ 3554.717863] usb 7-2: USB controller 0000:04:00.0 does not support streams, which are required by the UAS driver.
[ 3554.717873] usb 7-2: Please try an other USB controller if you wish to use UAS.
[ 3554.717883] usb-storage 7-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3554.724157] scsi host10: usb-storage 7-2:1.0
[49029.464801] usb 7-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[49029.480769] usb 7-3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[49029.480782] usb 7-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[49029.480791] usb 7-3: Product: ASMT1051
[49029.480800] usb 7-3: Manufacturer: asmedia
[49029.480808] usb 7-3: SerialNumber: 123456789012
[49029.481716] usb-storage 7-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[49029.481907] usb-storage 7-3:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[49029.481967] scsi host11: usb-storage 7-3:1.0
```

Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux media 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a81:0205 Chesen Electronics Corp. PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0557:8021 ATEN International Co., Ltd CS1764A [CubiQ DVI KVMP Switch]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 011: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 007 Device 010: ID 152d:0562 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:0811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci -vvv`

```
...
04:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL80x xHCI USB 3.0 Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL80x xHCI USB 3.0 Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 33
    Region 0: Memory at febff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Output of `lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/8p, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

Output of `usb-devices`

```
...
T:  Bus=07 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:04:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=07 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 10 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=152d ProdID=0562 Rev=01.03
S:  Manufacturer=JMicron
S:  Product=JMS56x Series
S:  SerialNumber=RANDOM__E3F4917AD758
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=8mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage

T:  Bus=07 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#= 11 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=174c ProdID=55aa Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=asmedia
S:  Product=ASMT1051
S:  SerialNumber=123456789012
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=144mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `usb-devices` reports `Driver=uas` on USB3 streaming mode or `Driver=usb-storage` on USB2. I see you left it connected on the chipset `SerialNumber=0000:04:00.0` device and it's indeed registered as `Driver=usb-storage` USB2 device, named `JMicron` as device 1 (`Cnt=01`) on that Bus.

Verified the `Driver=` options myself with my Aukey USB3 2.5" SATA enclousure. However, I didn't get your `streaming`-error in dmesg when connecting it to USB2, but my USB3 driver seems to be `xhci_hcd` as well.

My kernel version is `4.4.0-67-generic #88-Ubuntu`, under 16.04 x64. (my USB3: Onboard `ASRock B85M 1150` : `Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset`)

Sidenote:

You have a [VL800/VL801](http://www.via-labs.com/product_show.php?id=51) PCI-E USB3 card which is [PCIE 2.0 capable but only x1 wide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions) and is limited to 250-500 MByte/s, very likely bottlenecking all devices combined on this card. Bear in mind that even when you get this card working, you'd be stuck with that limitation, since the data can't get any faster to other peripherals in your PC.

You could try another cable (thicker and shorter is usually better) or omit any external USB hub which may be in the signal path. Personally, I'd go with another card (after researching its Linux-friendliness & PCI-E width & extra internal Power Plug to support High Power USB3 delivery).

Sorry, that's all I got.